# A riddle of two groups

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

I tried to join two different groups from very different towns
I was sure that one would let me in but both have turned me down
The first said they already have all personnel they need
they didn't seem to care that I adhere to their creed

"*The five of us can manage without another in the mix*
*In any case you belong elsewhere in a different gang of six!*"
But when I tried to join the other group of which they spoke
their members viewed my presence as if it were a joke

The first group were convinced that this was where I would belong
but the second group insisted that they must have heard me wrong
I don't fit in the sextet or the previous quintet
I must belong to something, have you figured it out yet?

**What am I?

Who are the two groups?

And why don't I belong in either of them?**

Comment: Very pleasant riddle!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to say

> "Y" or "Why", with the first group being the vowels, as it is sometimes considered a vowel. However the vowels misheard it as "Why" sending him to the group containing "Who, What, Where, When, Why, How"? (I don't know if this is officially a group, I just learnt them as "the 5Ws and How" summarising almost all questions :p)

Comment: You may be onto something, but to prevent guessing the answer I have updated the question so the correct answer must include an explanation of who the two groups are.

Comment: Of course, that's fine, and usually expected :)

Comment: Your answer includes all the thinking you should need to crack it. +1!

Comment: Ah of course! I knew there was a reference to them as a group somewhere :p

Answer (score 0):

i think you might be a:

> contrabass

and the two groups you tried to join were

> a *wind quintet* and a *rock sextet*

while the sextet you were supposed to join was

> a *jazz sextet*

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> **Time**?

I tried to join two different groups from very different towns
I was sure that one would let me in but both have turned me down

> The groups are "Senses" and "Directions", two very different groups in many aspects. (Also, "down" is one of the directions)

The first said they already have all personnel they need
they didn't seem to care that I adhere to their creed
"The five of us can manage without another in the mix

> Although humans definitely have some kind of a sense of time (and many others senses as well), the only senses "in the elite club" are the classical five: sight, hearing, taste, smell and touch.

In any case you belong elsewhere in a different gang of six!"
But when I tried to join the other group of which they spoke
their members viewed my presence as if it were a joke

> The other group are the six directions, forward, backward, up, down, left, and right.
>  At first glance, it seems ridiculous to think time should belong to the same group.

The first group were convinced that this was where I would belong

> Given Einstein's theory of special relativity, it makes **sense** that time should be [treated similarly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_spacetime) to the spatial dimensions, only that it doesn't really go in the negative direction like the other ones, which is why it makes some sense to think about it as "half a dimension".

but the second group insisted that they must have heard me wrong

> Hearing (wrong) is one of the five senses.
>  (In the correct solution, the wordplay most likely goes here.)

I don't belong in the sextet or the previous quintet

I must belong to something, have you figured it out yet?

> Time belongs to the Tower. --[Stephen King](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/653675-time-belongs-to-the-tower)

At this point I'm pretty much convinced this isn't IT. (Trying to stay on the King theme here..) Posting anyway, since a couple of the clues fit quite nicely.