# I'm one of many brothers

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I'm in the air and I'm in the ocean,
To the ones like Shakespeare goes my devotion.
I get confused by my seeing,
yet completely different my meaning.
Sometimes big and sometimes small,
when I protect, you won't see me at all.

What am I?
Hint in the title.
Hint 2:

> Line 1: Also in many other things, but only visible with a very good microscope ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you:

> The letter O?

I'm one of many brothers

> O is one of the vowel family

I'm in the air and I'm in the ocean,

> O is the symbol for *oxygen* found in air(O2) and water (H2O). Credit to @GileBrt for mentioning this first in comment.

To the ones like Shakespeare goes my devotion.

> Shakespeare used 'O' as an exclamation, as was the case in old English (eg *O Mistress mine where are you roaming? O stay and hear, your true love's coming*)

I get confused by my seeing,
yet completely different my meaning.

> (with credit to @MrDeadSven) could refer to the fact that 0(zero) and the letter O *look* the same but have completely different meaning.

Sometimes big and sometimes small,

> Upper case O, lower case o.

when I protect, you won't see me at all.

> When the letter protects another vowel it is not heard.

Comment: Nope that wasn't on purpose. You are on the right track, just not the one I was thinking off. 1st line has a different meaning and line 3& 4 are different. But it's one of  it's brothers.

Comment: @PeterS Okay... second guess?

Comment: Still not, I'll add some hints.

Comment: I was thinking that it's the letter O. Because of H2O (in the ocean) and there is oxygen (O2) in the air. :)

Comment: @PeterS Ok last attempt.

Comment: Correct, yet you skipped lines 3 and 4 :)

Comment: @PeterS is it rot13(b naq 0 gung n mreb ybbxf yvxr na b ohg vg'f pbzcyrgryl qvssrerag), for 3 and 4 this was the first thing that came to my mind?

Comment: @PeterS Thanks for a fun puzzle. I wrote a riddle involving the same set of brothers.... https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64388/a-riddle-of-two-groups